# Creating an RTF file with custom Drupal module

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, rtf

I want to be able to pass a node id to a path and generate an RTF file. I am having problems loading the library. I am using the Libraries 2 method. The error is:

```
PHP Fatal error: Class 'PHPRtfLite' not found in [redacted]/sites/all/modules/custom/ain_export/ain_export.module on line 22 request_id="245a0131-9519-4fa9-a512-3b60d0b91ad8"
```

So I've been making sure the files are where they should be. In my /sites/all/libraries directory I have a folder called 'phprtflite', set up like this:

```
-- phprtflite
----PHPRtfLite.php
```

Below is my code, now edited per the comment below to load the library inside my callback. I am still getting the error, except now on line 41. It seems to not be loading the library?

```
<?php

/**
* Implements hook_libraries_info().
*/
function ain_export_libraries_info() {
    $libraries['phprtflite'] = array(
      'name' => 'PHPRtfLite',
      'vendor url' => 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprtf/',
      'download url' => 'http://sourceforge.net/projects/phprtf/',
      'files' => array(
        'php' => array('PHPRtfLite.php'),
      ),
    );
    return $libraries;
}


/**
* Implements hook_menu().
*/
function ain_export_menu() {
    $items = array();    
    $items['admin/ain_export/%'] = array(
        'title' => 'Export Node',
        'page callback' => 'ain_export_page',
        'page arguments' => array(2),
        'access arguments' => array('access administration pages'),
      );

    return $items;
}

// spit out node
function ain_export_page($nid) {

    // load library
    libraries_load('phprtflite');

    // register PHPRtfLite class loader
    PHPRtfLite::registerAutoloader();

  if (isset($nid) ) {
      try {

          $rtf = new PHPRtfLite();

          // set page properties
          $rtf->setMargins(2.54, 2.54, 2.54, 2.54);
          $rtf->setPaperFormat(PHPRtfLite::PAPER_LETTER);

          // define fonts
          $fontH1 = new PHPRtfLite_Font(16, 'Arial', '#000000');
          $fontH2 = new PHPRtfLite_Font(14, 'Arial', '#000000');
          $fontP = new PHPRtfLite_Font(12, 'Arial', '#000000');

          // vertical space
          $formatH1 = new PHPRtfLite_ParFormat();
          $formatH1->setSpaceAfter(8);
          $formatH2 = new PHPRtfLite_ParFormat();
          $formatH2->setSpaceAfter(6);
          $formatP = new PHPRtfLite_ParFormat();
          $formatP->setSpaceAfter(3);

          // page content
          $node = node_load($nid); // load the node

          // headline
          $section = $rtf->AddSection();
          $section->writeText($node->title, $fontH1, $formatH1);


          // output file
          $rtf->SendRtf( $nid . '.rtf' );


      } catch (Exception $e) {
          $error = $e->getMessage();
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: `libraries_load()` and other code should not be in the top level of your .module file; it should be in the callback function. Speaking of which, please also give us the code for that callback function. (And, more pedantically, tabs in proper Drupal code style only have two spaces, not four.)

Comment: Okay, I see you added the callback code, but I also see that you didn't try moving libraries_load() into it.